# postgresql: join syntax error when joining 2 select statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, syntax

I am querying the aact database from clinicaltrials.gov. The database model is right here: https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/schema. I have two schemas that I am selecting from (ctgov, proj_cdek_standard_orgs).  I am trying to join two select statements. **edit**: I have now tried aliasing my subqueries, but that still does nothing. I get the following error:

```
(SELECT ctgov.sponsors.name, ctgov.sponsors.nct_id, ctgov.sponsors.id, ctgov.studies.phase
FROM ctgov.sponsors, ctgov.studies
WHERE ctgov.sponsors.nct_id=ctgov.studies.nct_id) A

FULL [OUTER] JOIN


(SELECT proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.id, proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name
FROM proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms) B

ON

A.name = B.name;
```

I can do both select statements perfectly fine on their own, but I try the query and I get this error:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t1" LINE 7: ) t1`

What did I do wrong and how do I use joins without getting syntax errors?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. PS Re "how do I use joins without getting syntax errors" Don't ask us to (re)write yet another presentation of SQL, justify why you think that will work per some authoritative presenatation so we can address your misconceptions/misreadings. Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT ctgov.sponsors.name, ctgov.sponsors.nct_id, ctgov.sponsors.id, 
    ctgov.studies.phase, proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.id, 
    proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name
FROM ctgov.sponsors, ctgov.studies, proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms
WHERE ctgov.sponsors.nct_id=ctgov.studies.nct_id
and proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name = ctgov.sponsors.name;
```

But the right way is to use traditional joins,

```
SELECT ctgov.sponsors.name, ctgov.sponsors.nct_id, ctgov.sponsors.id, 
    ctgov.studies.phase, proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.id, 
    proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name
FROM ctgov.sponsors
INNER JOIN ctgov.studies
ON (ctgov.sponsors.nct_id=ctgov.studies.nct_id)
INNER  JOIN proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms
ON (proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name = ctgov.sponsors.name);
```

You can change it to LEFT or FULL OUTER JOIN according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an alias to the sub-queries. Also you should not use implicit joins as you have used in first subquery, always try to use explicit joins.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ctgov.sponsors.name, ctgov.sponsors.nct_id, ctgov.sponsors.id, ctgov.studies.phase
  FROM ctgov.sponsors
  JOIN ctgov.studies
  ON ctgov.sponsors.nct_id=ctgov.studies.nct_id
) t1

FULL JOIN


(
  SELECT 
    proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.id, proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms.name
  FROM proj_cdek_standard_orgs.cdek_synonyms
) t2

ON

t1.name = t2.name;
```